# Linux script groupadd

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have a groupadd script:

```
#/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter new group name: "
read group
if egrep "^$group" /etc/group; then
    cut -d: -f1 /etc/group
    echo "!!Group $group already exists!!"
    echo -n "Enter different group name: "
    read  name
    groupadd $name
    echo "Group $name was created."
else
    groupadd $group
    echo "Group $group was crated."
fi
```

This script works perfectly fine. But I run into small problem which I have trouble to figure it out how to deal with that problem.

The problem starts when I'm entering Hello and there is already group Hello. It says group Hello already exists.  The line Enter different group name pops and I again enter Hello. It shows this which bothers me because I can't deal with it:

```
groupadd: group "Hello" already exists
Group Hello was created.
```

But I  want to do another group check loop when entering for second time Hello and not ending the script like in the example above.

So if there will be someone to show me how to deal with this I'll be happy :)

Thanks :)

Comment: @Andy why not post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to use `getent group $group > /dev/null 2>&1` instead of manual grepping. Second, you may do a while loop like `while read x; do; … ; done`.